# What is the best place in data generation to handle html creation (server side or clientside)

Tags: javascript, php

I am writing a dashboard application that gets data from a php function which communicates with a db on the same server. This data is then called by an api call on a webpage. The JS code then loops through the requested data (differs based on given params) and creates the html code to display a table below a graph. The way this JS code creates the html code is simply by adding strings together and then pushing it to the relevant innerhtml.

My question is since only a string is needed for this table code would it be more efficient to let the php (server side) code handle the html generation, or let the JS code handle the html code generation. The itteration steps wont change just where the html string is being generated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The client side generation would be faster and more efficient, because generation on the server will increase load on your server, and also will need more bandwith to send the complete html file.

Eg, if you have 10k users on your website, you'll have to generate 10k html files ( increases processing) , and then send those to all of the users ( increases bandwidth).

Doing it on the client side means, client gets the data first, and then it can generate its own html, and this will be faster as the client would not need to wait for the html file.